# Server keeps going down

Tags: mysql

My brother and i share a dedicated linux server, with Plesk CP. On this server we have 4 MYSQL databases, plus my sound files for my music site. our ASP is hosted elsewhere.  For the last few days the server has been going down, and simultaneously, none of the sites can connect to the server.  Usually the error is this

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

but we also get this error on some occasions :-

```
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Host 'server213-171-218-93.livedns.org.uk' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

i have ran a flush-hosts and this will help for a little while, but within a few hours the sites will be down again

we have 4 sites running, and when one is down, they will all be down.  I can still access the control panel, and when i look at the MYSQL engine, it is still running, and i can browse the tables etc.

i have checked the number of concurrent connections for all the databases and it is never above 10 or so.

i have not been messing with any of the scripts of the sites for a long time, so i am at a loss as what is causing it to crash.  we have had this server for a few years, and it has been fine until now.

i did notice that the query stats seemed quite high, as we only get about 500 hits a day to all 4 sites combined. here is a copy and paste of the stats:-

Query statistics: Since its startup, 34,358 queries have been sent to the server. (this was in 6 hours since it was rebooted)

i thought we may have been hacked, so changed all passwords, but that didnt help

anyone have any ideas what else i should look into?

Answer (score 0):

> many connection errors

show that there is some communication problem.

You could raise `max_connect_errors` to give you time to find issue.
Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html

Comment: we raised the max. number of connections allowed to 500 a few months ago, as we had a few problems, and this seemed to help with that particular problem since then, we found the script that wasnt closing the database, and fixed that problem.  now, when checking the maximum number of connections in the server stats, it never has more than 20 concurrent connections, so i am not sure that raising it any further would help

Comment: I'm talking about setting to allow more error before host being banned.

Comment: oh i see...... thanks Dr evil..... i have looked at the CP and the max. number allowed at present is 10.  what do you think is a safe value to set it to, without causing any problems elsewhere??

Comment: This setting only causes server to ban host after N errors.
But you still need to find a reason of getting such errors.
Errors could be caused by long queryes (over max-wait-time), for example.

Comment: Also, check your mysql error log.

Comment: the things is Dr Evil, we have not changed the code of the site, or anything on the server for a long time, and previously the server was running great.  now all of a sudden it keeps crashing.  the mysql is still running, as i can check it in the control panel, but we keep getting this error   [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0.  so the mysql is still running, but the asp pages, hosted on another server, fail to connect.  with this information, do you still think changing the max_connect_errors will help?

Comment: (thanks a lot for taking the time to help mate :o))

Comment: Check these settings:
connect_timeout
interactive_timeout
net_read_timeout   
net_write_timeout
wait_timeout

For example, if connect_timeout set to 1 second, and connect, and wait for more that 1 second - you will get such error.

Comment: Might be worth looking at the number of connections coming in on the webservers, to see if you are being DOS'd.

Comment: dr evil.....

these are the variables you said to check

connect timeout 5

interactive timeout 28,800

net read timeout 30

net write timeout 60

table lock wait timeout 50

how do those figures look mate?

Comment: Jason Tan - the only traffic stats i can find via the Plesk CP is the following... Query statistics: Since its startup, 2,600 queries have been sent to the server. (this is in 30 mins, since we had to reboot).... is this the stats you mean, or are other stats available?

Comment: Other :)
Try 
mysqladmin variables

Comment: sorry Dr evil..... i dont follow.....  1 - are those figures above re - timeouts ok you think?  2 - how do i locate mysqladmin variables?